# 8-Bit stereo audio R-2R DAC, is this a right way to do it?

Tags: dac, register

I am new to electrical engineering and the first project I would like to do is making a digital to analog audioconverter. I've found out that a good way to do this is to use an R-2R structure for the conversion.

I'd like to challenge myself and start from scratch with the digital part of the circuit, besides the fact that I can't really find any solutions on the web to help building it. I've got a circuit simulation program and started designing, while searching the web for all different kinds of electronics you might use for it.

Now I think I might be somewhere in the neighbourhood of understanding the principle of a DAC, but it would be helpful if someone experienced could help me check if I do in fact get it. Is this a right place to ask for that?

If so, here's the circuit I've designed:
[image: 8-Bit stereo audio R-2R DAC]

I have used a shift register with output latch for each channel and linked Q7S from one to the other to feed the data. Is it right that audio files alternate left and right channel, or vice versa, in blocks? e.g. in an 8-bit file: 0010 0111 for left following 0010 0110 for right?

The shift registers I've used here are 74HC595s. When shifting-in bits non of the pins will be (momentarily) be active. When the latch [STCP pin] is triggered the bits get transferred from the shift register into the storage register, where they will directly output their value to the corresponding pins and stay active until the next 16 bits are allowed in.

Then there is the crystal, for which I've used a square wave signal to imitate one with the right oscillating frequency: 24,576MHz. It feeds the counter in which the frequency gets divided to output the frequencies my DAC needs. In this case the sample frequency has to be 192.000kHz and therefore the frequency at which the data is shifted in has to be 3.02MHz (192.000 x 16 bit). The 192.000kHz clock speed is used to trigger STCP.

The next thing I want to do is to figure out how to load data from a source (Raspberry for example) through maybe I2C into a buffer in the DAC and from there clock the bits out into the circuit you see here.

If you think I am or I am not on the right way, it would be very helpful to let me know.

Thanks!
Rogier

By the way, I forgot to mention that the DAC I would like to build is at least 24-bit per channel at 96kHZ. It just takes up a lot of space on this threat and shouldn't be difficult to add them afterwards. It's the same principle.

Comment: Good, difficult project. I didn't go through all your maths but an 8-bit audio isn't going to sound too good. You're going to have to bias to half-supply which leaves you with 7-bit on each side. You may get away with this on compressed speech where dynamic range is severely limited but quiet passages of speech or music will have terrible distortion due to the coarse step size and the ear's logarithmic response. From memory, CD quality is 14-bit.

Comment: @transistor while it won't qualify has high fidelity, 8-bit audio can be surprisingly listenable if done right, especially if the sample rate is out of the audible range, which it seems to be in this case (with a high enough sample rate, you can even get away with 1-bit output...).  A more serious concern is if the shift registers proposed are "double-buffered", or if bits will momentatarily show up on the wrong outputs while being shifted through, something that could cause substantial distortion.

Comment: +1 for a decent question. It's not going to be hi-fi, but it's a darn good way to learn about how difficult it is to make a good DAC :)

Comment: I2C is probably far too slow as a data source - it maxes out at 400kHz (well there is a 3.4MHz FM+ mode, but most things don't support that). You could look at USB - there are some microcontrollers out there which support being a USB slave audio device without needing to write windows/linux drivers. Did a quick search and found this [Atmel app note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32139.pdf). Could use something like that to get the data and then hook up your shift registers via SPI.

Comment: @transistor You can keep all 8 bits by using coupling capacitors to "center" your ac output & even with a vcc/2 bias, you can still divide that 0.5vcc by 256 in the R-2R DAC for full-resolution @ 8 bits.

Comment: i dunno what serial-to-parallel chip you're using is.  but you might want to make sure that the output voltages for both **ON** and **OFF** are consistent between all of the outputs.  otherwise, you may need to buffer the digital outputs to make them analog precise.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: Can you explain further your last comment? My thinking was that we would have to make the MSB into an inverted 'sign' bit so that at rest the DAC input is 1000 0000 (midpoint). Positive going signals go 1000 0001, 1000 0010, etc. Negative going signals go 0111 1111, 0111 1110, etc. giving only 127 steps each side of zero, i.e., 7-bits.

Comment: As to your comment about 24 bits per channel - forget it, forget it now, and don't waste any more time thinking about it. I'm not going to go in to the maths for that in this comment, but I'm sure it's come up here some time before. If not, here's what wikipedia has to say: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder#Accuracy_of_R.E2.80.932R_resistor_ladders

Comment: @transistor. Thanks for all your replies. I forgot to mention that my ultimate goal is to build a 24bit DAC. In my first attempt I'll probably not be using over-sampling as it makes it far more complex. It shouldn't be difficult to softwarematically add some zeros to the end of each block, to fit the DAC's input.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson he's handling the serial-to-parallel conversion himself, using a clock source and 2 shift registers (the 3 ICs in his diagram).

Comment: @pipe Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure I understand. 24bit audio is audibly better than 16bit, isn't it. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: I mean that you are not going to get close to even 16 bit using an R-2R ladder. It's good for things like 8 bit (actually not even then). Things like output/input impedance, resistor noise, resistance mismatch etc.

Comment: @transistor I think that's more of a software protocol choice as the whether tl use msb as sign (+127/-128), or use an unsigned byte (0-256), but either way, you technically still have 256 discrete output power levels, so same resolution, just a different "reference point" (0=vcc, or 0=vcc/2). I think the convention would be to use unsigned...but I could definitely be wrong on that assumption.

Comment: Oh, and yes, you can use any convention, signed or unsigned, it's the discrete number of steps that counts, not if they go from -vcc to 0, -vcc/2 to vcc/2, or 0 to vcc. @transistor is just confused. :)

Comment: @pipe What would be an alternative method for achieving good quality 24bit output? I thought almost every DAC on the market uses this R-2R technique. I think it's a good practice to start with this one anyway.

Comment: No DAC will use this technique, because it's very difficult constructing resistors on a chip, and even if you laser-trim them and use special substrates you'll only going to get at most 16 bits of resolution. It's still a good project to start with. If you start doing the maths you'll realize that to make a 24-bit output you have to accurately control nanovolts. That's going to be the noise in one resistor if you're not careful.

Comment: As pipe notes, making a 24 bit DAC is *very* challenging; layout becomes critical as does keeping the audio path clean. Digital noise feedthrough and other issues mean that this is difficult to achieve. I applaud your desire to do something that tough. I will note that most 24 bit devices are delta-sigma designs. There is an excellent application note that goes into some detail at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa055/sbaa055.pdf

Comment: Thanks @pipe and Peter Smith, I will keep it in mind! My expectations as far as to audio quality goes shouldn't be very high. Still, it's a good educative project to finish!

Comment: Using 1% resistors, you can get accurate 6-bit resolution (LSB=MSB/64, so 1% error < LSB/MSB value), but above that you'd need to cut the possible error per resistor in half for every additional bit (0.25% for 8-bit) too keep resistor error from possibly overpowering your least significant bit(s).

Comment: For accurate resolution above 8-bit, you should probably use some form of PWM

Comment: As the beauty of R2R is that the resistor ratio is important rather than the absolute value of the devices, a matched array can be used for at least 8 bit precision, such as http://www.bitechnologies.com/pdfs/resistorladder.pdf and http://www.vishayprecisiongroup.com/foil-resistors/voltage-dividers-networks/ Not cheap though.

Comment: BTW, @PeterSmith, you ain't gonna do **any** 24-bit DAC with R-2R.  but you *might* do 24-bits with an 8-bit or 6-bit R-2R and, a great deal of oversampling (like \$F_s\$ = 3 MHz), and maybe some kinda noise shaping like in Sigma Delta.  and those 24-bit audio DACs are not an honest 24 bits.  there are some "marketing bits" in there.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Marketing bits? :| I feel some kind of urge now to build a really good 24-bit DAC, just to not ever have to buy "marketing bits" (or spend thousands). It's gonna be a tough job and seemingly I have to use another technique than R-2R! ;)

Comment: \$ 2^{-23} \$ is an awful small number.  like 1 over 8 million.  you will not be able to make a DAC, with any decent conversion speed, that has output as accurate as that spec.  the **honest** number of bits is the Dynamic Range in dB (which is the S/N ratio in dB added to the number of dB of headroom) divided by 6.02 dB/bit.  that will give you the number of honest bits.  the best i have seen in the industry is still about 20 bits (or about 120 dB dynamic range).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: A DAC which could take 24-bit random samples and output anything near 24-bit resolution would be very expensive, but one which could e.g. take a 24-bit signal containing a 100Hz signal at -1dB with a superimposed on a 10KHz signal at -96dB and yield an output which accurately registers both signals would be much easier even though the 10Khz signal would be completely lost in 16-bit signal.

Comment: @Robert: I did not say that a 24 bit DAC was achievable with resistors - I said that 8 bits was achievable with a precision array.

Answer (score 7):

- Yes, this is *exactly* the right place to ask your question.
- Yes, R-2R topography is the simplest to design (and I think best) way to make a homebrew DAC (wkthout using PWM).
- As for challenging yourself, it sounds to me like you may be about as masochistic as I am (kudos for having the guts!). This is a **really** involved project for a beginner.
- Your R-2R resistor strings (and arguably the attached op amps) actually ARE your 8-bit DACs

Here's what I'm thinking:
[image: Corrected Ladder]

Unfortunately, the [wikipedia page on R-2R ladder DACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder#R.E2.80.932R_resistor_ladder_network_.28digital_to_analog_conversion.2C_or_DAC.29) is incorrect when it says that the R-2R ladder functions as a current divider in this application. While an R-2R ladder *can* be used as a current divider, it actually functions as a voltage divider here. Here's a detailed analysis.

Consider just the LSB of the ladder by itself:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCK7b7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regardless of the position of the switch, the Thevenin resistance of this simple voltage divider is just R. The value of the Thevenin voltage source is either 0V or 1/2 × Vref.

Now, consider what happens when you add the next stage of the R-2R ladder:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9oloG.png)</sup>

You can see that this is the same kind of voltage divider that we had in the first case, except that the number of voltage combinations has increased. However, the Thevenin resistance of this circuit is *still* just R, and the Thevenin voltage source is now 0/4, 1/4, 2/4 or 3/4 × Vref.

By induction, you can see that you can add any number of stages to the ladder, and the only effect is that the number of choices for the Thevenin voltage source value gets multiplied by 2 for each stage. The source resistance remains exactly the same for any number of stages.

If the load impedance is infinite, the output voltage of the ladder will exactly match the Thevenin voltage. But if the load has some finite value of resistance, the only effect will be to create a voltage divider with the Thevenin source resistance, scaling the output voltage by some fixed ratio, but having no other effect on the DAC's basic accuracy or linearity.

---

Note that in Rogier's original circuit (the one in the question), the opamps are in an inverting configuration, which means that the output of the R-2R ladder is tied directly to a virtual ground. This means that the output value is really the current flowing through Rth (which is just R), and this current also flows through the opamp's feedback resistor. The output voltage from the opamp is whatever voltage that is required to make those two currents equal, and works out to -Rfb/R × Vth. Since he uses a feedback resistor of 2R, the output ends up being -2 × Vth.

---

There seems to be some confusion over whether the R-2R ladder is being used as a voltage divider or a current divider, so here's an illustration of how the latter can work, in order to show the key differences between this and the OP's circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgtc6f.png)</sup>

Note that the currents flowing down through the 2R resistors are binary-weighted. This works because the effective resistance looking to the right from any of the triple junctions is also exactly 2R. Therefore, the current flowing from the left always divides equally between the down branch and the right branch.

Note that a key assumption here is that all of the legs are tied to the same voltage (zero, in this case). It is also interesting to note that the voltages at the junction nodes are also binary-weighted.

This can be used to build a *current-output* DAC as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGqYEN.png)</sup>

The currents in the resistors in this circuit are exactly the same as the previous diagram, because regardless of which position each of the switches is in, the corresponding resistor is connected either to a real ground on the \$\overline{\text{Iout}}\$ bus, or to a virtual ground on the \$\text{Iout}\$ bus. The currents on the two busses always add up to Iref. An opamp can convert the output current to a voltage, and the voltage range is simply -Iref × R7.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't actually know what an opamp does and why I would need it here. What it does (according to the simulation software) is making the positive signal coming out of the R-2R ladder negative with a multiple of two: ~5V in, -9,96V out. Why would that be necessary?

Comment: Op Amps magnify the _difference_ between 2 input voltages.so the software is saying you have your MSB attached to the inverting input (minus sign pin) of the op amp, causing the output to vary as the opposite of the input. The ratio of output signal voltage to input voltage is controlled by the feedback (you used 10K) resistor from op amp output to op amp inverting input; the higher the resistance, the more gain you get (shorting across that resistor, then moving the MSB connect to op amp + input & LSB  connect to ground should fix this.

Comment: Not really. In the OP's diagram, the noninverting inputs of the opamps ARE grounded. All you're doing is switching to a voltage-follower configuration. Don't forget to include a 5k resistor in the feedback path of each one to balance the bias current offsets. Also, the bottommost resistor in each of your R-2R ladders needs to be 10K, not 5K. The OP had this right, too.

Comment: Robherc, 1. i would ditch the coupling capacitors.  2. if you keeping with the non-inverting voltage follower circuit you have, then you need to add a 10K resistor from the + terminal of the op-amps to ground.  and the 5K resistor on the bottom should be 10 K.  imagine superposition and all bits *OFF* (or ground).  when you're sitting at any of those nodes, it should be 10K of resistance to ground in all 3 directions.

Comment: Diagram updated with corrected grounding. @robertbristow-johnson why would you get rid of the capacitors that block dc & center your output to protect the tranducers in an audio circuit?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The extra 10k resistors to ground on the noninverting inputs to the opamps are useless; all they do is create a voltage divider with the 5k source resistance of the R-2R ladder itself, reducing the output voltage by a factor of 2/3.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: And your comparison to a DC-coupled product is irrelevant -- undoubtedly it used *bipolar* ADCs and DACs that could handle analog voltages both above and below ground. That isn't the kind of DAC we're talking about here.

Comment: It just dawned on me that even using just `74HC595`s you can still get a standard-conforming I2S input.

Comment: @DaveTweed, your first comment about the 10K resistor from the noninverting terminal to ground is just wrong.  do the nodal analysis.  without that 10K resistor on both bookends, the binary weighting does not happen exactly.  and i thought the problem here was completely agnostic about bipolar vs. unipolar.  of course an audio product without a DC blocking capacitor would need a bipolar supply and such.

Comment: and i dunno if these Qn outputs of the digital device will need pull-up resistors or not, but i am still concerned (and i mentioned this in a comment on the question) about the different Qn outputs not having precisely the same *ON* voltage or even the same *OFF* voltage.  if their good open-collector and precision pull-up resistors are used (and tied to the same + voltage source), **perhaps** some adjustment to the other resistors can be made, but, given super-position, i rather doubt it.  so the Qn outputs need to be the same low output impedance whether they are *ON* or *OFF*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I HAVE done the analysis, and I'm NOT wrong on this one. The digital inputs to an R-2R ladder are voltage sources of either 0V or Vcc, and the output of an N-bit ladder can be modeled as a voltage source of \$V_{CC}\frac{n}{2^N}\$ in series with a resistance of R (exactly!), where "n" is the binary input value that varies from \$0\$ to \$2^N - 1\$.

Comment: there are a lotta bad examples out there with Google, not just Wikipedia.  one good reference with an [inverting op-amp](http://www.daenotes.com/electronics/digital-electronics/digital-to-analog-converters) and other one that is closer to yours, Rob, with [non-inverting op-amp](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-following-r-2r-resistor-ladder-circuit-find-output-switch-node-3-connected-vr-assume-q2200901).

Comment: By my current re-examination of the circuit, using trace-following procedure, I'm seeing the R-2R ladder giving the MSB to the op amp input at 9/11 VCC (10K between Q1 & op amp; 45K between op amp & GND, yielding 45K/55K=9/11 voltage divider). Meanwhile, with a 10K "bookend" resistor works in parallel with the 45K down-ladder resistance to create a ~8.2K path to GND, making the voltage divider ~8.2/18.2=4.1/9.1

Comment: Reworking the parallel resistance equation to create a 10K path to GND, and thus a voltage divider that yields a _true_ VCC/2 representation of MSB, yields an ideal "bookend" resistor value of ~12.857K

Comment: i don't get the 9/11, but without the bookend 10K at the MSB end, if you look at the three-wire node at 2nd MSB, it's 15K in the up direction, 10K in the left direction and 10K in the down direction.  that 15K *should* be 10K to maintain the recursive symmetry going up and down the ladder.  imagine what the impedances were if there were no bookends, just books (or steps) going up and down the ladder forever.

Comment: no, it's not 12.857K either.  the bookends **must** be 2R.  one by the LSB and another by the MSB.  and it's to maintain a consistent similar topology for each bit, going up and down the ladder.

Comment: my other worry, is the output impedance of the digital outputs.  maybe if it's CMOS, you'll be okay, because there is a pull-up MOSFET as well as the pull-down MOSFET that you would get in other logic families like open-drain or something.  but what you want is the **same** output impedance (which would be subtracted from the 10K resistors in series with the output) for both *ON* and *OFF*.

Comment: Rob, i am saying break **any** of those three-wire nodes and look at what you have for impedances going into any of the three paths.  it **must** be consistent for each of those nodes in order for the precise current bisecting to happen.

Comment: Shift registers are double-bufferred with latch-and-hold output flipflop stage. Thus each outpit "bit" should be equally close to VCC or GND. All outputs are pulled down by the R-2R ladder itself, so separate pulldown resistors would be redundant.

Comment: but if the output impedances are not the same for Qn=Vcc or Qn=GND, then you will have another problem with consistent weighting of the bits.  the model you're going with is, not just consistent output voltage (and we **know** there is goofy stuff inside of logic chips that may cause them to have inconsistent voltages as long as they remain within the very loose digital spec) but an ideal voltage source.   that is important to know what it the output impedance is, and to subtract it out of the 10K resistor in series.

Comment: Ok, if I add 20K linear pots (from Op Amp + input to GND)  & instructions to adjust pot resistance until MSB is as close as possible to VCC, can we agree on that being accurate enough for the OP's stated intent for this project?

Comment: no.  just put in good 1% fixed resistors, but accept that there will be problems if the output voltages between the bits are not consistent and if the output impedances change going from 0 to 1.  the R-2R model uses ideal voltage sources.  BTW, i did this 4 decades ago.  worked okay to about 6 bits.

Comment: Yes, there will be fluctuations. Luckily, though, the error value of each bit is reduced to 1/2^n (for Q0, n=0; Q1, n=1; etc.) of original error, so as long as Q0 and Q1 are reproduced with high precision, the lower-order bits' errors are of fairly minimal comparative importance _especially_ considering auditory logarythmic response).

Comment: i haven't heard back from @DaveTweed, but will re-affirm that he is wrong in his assertion that 2R bookend resistors are not needed on both ends of the R-2R ladder.  if he insists that his nodal analysis leads him to that mistaken conclusion, he should spell it out.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: For some reason, the system was not showing me the comments made last night after my last comment. I have now rolled back the answer to the correct diagram, and added a little tutorial on the analysis of the R-2R ladder used as a voltage DAC. This is based on material I first presented in my *Circuit Cellar* article "Digital Processing in an Analog World, Part 2: Technology Choices", issue #100, November 1998.

Comment: @DaveTweed I see how your tutorial works when switched "bits" are switched  SPDT (to either vcc or gnd), but how would this work if the data input device uses a SPST-type logical data representation? How would we then maintain a 2R path to gnd? (I thought of using pull-down resistors, but that would mess up the "on state" voltage division)

Comment: You can't use SPST switches. It is a fundamental assumption with this kind of DAC that the digital inputs are voltage sources (0V or Vref, zero source impedance) *at all times*. That's why CMOS logic is a good choice -- its outputs are more symmetrical than TTL.

Comment: Dave, the diagram that you rolled back to is wrong.  it needs the 10 K resistor at the bookend at the top.  if it doesn't have that, the currents will not bisect accurately in the R-2R ladder.  why are you so incapable of simply doing the nodal analysis?  what you need to do is break **any** of those three wire nodes, and confirm that you see the same 10 K impedance from that wire to ground with **all** three of the three wires connected to the node. if you do that for the 2nd-most significant bit, you will see a resistance of 15K instead of 10K down that wire, and the current will not bisect.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: What you can't seem to grasp here is that the ladder is NOT functioning as a "current divider" in this application. Show me specifically where my analysis is wrong, and I'll retract it.

Comment: every single node is a current divider.  and it **should** be a current bisector.  your output will not be proportional to the binary word value (what you call "\$n\$") as the circuit stands now.  i have clearly explained why.  if you break any of the three-wire nodes, you **must** be looking at the same impedance in all three directions, in order for this to work accurately.  by all objective analysis, you're just wrong here, Dave.  it needs that 10K resistor on the top.  it is **not** "useless" but is part of the arithmetic inherent to the R-2R ladder.

Comment: what's wrong with your analysis is that you have the resistances wrong.  you think you have an "R" when you don't have exactly that R.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: You just keep saying the same thing over and over again, with no math/diagram/details to back it up. Yes, there are various currents flowing through the resistors in this ladder, and they change with the switch settings, but there's no requirement or desire that any of the currents be binary-weighted. I'm going to add a section that explains how an R-2R ladder can be used as the current divider in a current-output DAC, but only to show the contrast with the OP's circuit.

Comment: To get clean output from your DAC you'll need some filtering.  Audio equipment won't cleanly register signals above audio frequencies, but may not cleanly filter them out either, and the presence of such signals may induce distortion at audible frequencies.  I'd suggest adding a capacitor in parallel with the output of the resistor string such that the RC time constant of the string is 1.44 [e.g. 1/ln(2)] times the sample period and pre-emphasizing the output fed to the DAC such that each sample is twice the new value, minus the old value.

Comment: You'll need a little extra headroom on your signals to make that work, but if you can afford to pre-emphasize the signals digitally you can reduce the amount of analog filtering that will be needed afterward.

Comment: @supercat You're right, but the OP stated that this circuit is intended as a "learning experience," rather than as anything even remotely "hi-fi." However, if you move your suggested capacitor to the output of the Op Amp (so it doesn't load the R-2R resistors directly), then I completely agree to that being a useful filter for smoothing the output audio.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the path from MSB to gnd is already: MSB - 10K - op amp tap (separate path) - 10K - gnd. Each nodes "sees" the nodes below in the chain as a collective 10K path to gnd, and they actually are if all are 0 values, illustrate a 0-bit as a short to gnd to see it. I got confused along with you for a while there, but the SPDT thing is what we were looking at wrong). If it helps, picture the whole DAC as being fed by VCC/GND SPDT switches, rather than shift register output pins.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: I neglected that the OP's circuit uses an inverting rather than non-inverting op amp configuration so the cap should go across the feedback resistor.  If the cap is placed after the output of the op amp, the RC time constant (and thus frequency response) will depend upon the characteristics of the downstream input, which it may be difficult to model.  BTW, using pre-emphasis as described will not be a good approach from a frequency-domain perspective, but will greatly reduce the maximum slew rate without overly affecting "desired" frequency response.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: OK, I've added the additional material. Note that the ladder only works as a binary current splitter if all of the legs are tied to the same (effective) voltage. It's very different from how the voltage-output DAC works.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Your lack of response suggests that you are conceding at least some of the points you were previously arguing. If that's the case, I'd like to go through and clean out some of the numerous comments that have accumulated on this post. Please let me know one way or the other. (BTW, I'm not sure whether you're aware of this, but I'm the guy at the AES holiday party with whom you had the lengthy discussion about audio equalizer "Q" specifications. It's nice to see you here!)

Comment: nice to see you here too.  i just don't see the currents bisecting without the symmetry.   but i did the voltage divider for Q0 high (get 1/2) and then for Q1 high and it comes out as 1/4, so i am conceding that somehow it works (at least for those two bits) without bisecting the currents.  but if it doesn't bisect the currents, i can't see right now why Q2 should have exactly half the weighting that Q1 has.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: You simply have to let go of the notion that current division is what is at work here. Instead, focus on the idea that if you connect two voltage sources together with two equal resistances, the voltage at the center node is simply the average of the two sources: \$\frac{V1 + V2}{2}\$. It is this repeated division by two *of the voltages* that provides the weighting. In the R-2R ladder, one of the sources is always 0 or Vref, but as you cascade stages, the number of choices for the second source increases.

Comment: are you saying to let go of the notion of Kirchoff's current law (which i won't) or that the currents must bisect at each node?  apparently that's the only notion left. what makes the effect of Q7 be \$2^{-7}\$ the effect of Q0?  it's (ostensibly) because the current from Q7 is cut in half at 8 nodes in between while the current from Q0 is cut in half only once.  again, ostensibly, it's because each of those outputs are staring into the same load resistance and supply the same current when they are *ON* (and the others are *OFF*).  but that's not the case without the bookend resistors.

Comment: again, Dave, without re-analyzing the circuit for **each** and **every** bit being *ON* (and using superposition to generalize to all combinations), how do you prove that the effect of the Q\$n\$ bit is \$2^{-n}\$ the effect of the Q0 bit?  i see no pattern to make this case with.